# Combining two time series with different cadences (different Nyquist frequencies)...?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, sampling, nyquist, time-series

### If it helps, I want to do perform the below computation in python.

Two time-series - **30-min cadence** (Nyquist of 24 cycles / day) lasting 27 days, followed by **10-min cadence** (Nyquist of 72 cycles / day) lasting another 27 days. There may or may not be a gap in between these two time-series (*the 27 day observation may also be varied*)

**How can I legitimately combine the two time-series** so that my power-spectrum has maximum S/N? I don't want to throw out the 30-min cadence data; I'd like to use it to improve S/N at low frequencies.

I'm more interested in the Fourier domain of the data - the power-spectrum.

Comment: From the looks of it, it would be easiest to just up-sample the first sequence by a factor of three. Then you apply the same processing to both sequences and energy average the  results or just treat the whole thing as a single sequence.

Comment: @Hilmar you mean just interpolate the coarser sampling on the finer grid? Is that valid? I'm worried about  the aspect of"inventing" data that didn't exist

Comment: If you’re worried about that, you could also downsample the second sequence.

Comment: @PrasadMani: up-sampling is well defined mathematical process. You are not inventing more data , if you do it correctly. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsampling or ask a separate question about it.